# Git - creating a repo for a new user/ computer

Tags: git, git-clone

How do I set up a local repository for a new user using Git?

I am working on a Python/ Django project, and a new employee will be joining me soon, so I need to set up their computer ready to access all of the files on the repository, and ready for them to begin development work on the project.

I had not used Git much previously prior to starting work with this company, and when I joined, someone else had already set up my development environment, so that I had the latest copy of the code copied from the remote Git repository to my computer, ready for me to start developing on- so setting up an environment for a new user with an existing project is not something I've ever done before.

I've had a look online, and it looks like I want to run a `git clone` of the remote repository from the new user's computer, but I'm not sure how/ where to do this from?

I am using a Mac (OS X Yosemite), and my colleague will be too. On my computer, my 'root' development folder is at:

```
Macintosh HD > Users > me > Documents > Dev > myProgram > root
```

This is where all of the Django Apps, .json files and other 'system files' for the software seem to be.

To replicate this setup on my colleague's computer, do I just need to create the folder structure:

```
Dev > myProgram > root
```

on their computer, then `cd` to that location using the command line, and run the `git clone` command from there?

I am aware that I will need the address of the remote repository, to give to the `git clone` command- as I understand, I would find this by running `git remote -v` from my computer? Is that correct?

Presumably then I would need to run `git clone remoteAddress` from `Dev > myProgram > root` on my colleague's computer?

**Edit**

I will obviously want to add the user to the Django project too- I tried doing this via www.mysite.co.uk/admin and going to Authentication & Authorisation -> Add User, I set up the username & password, and gave the user profile admin privileges. It said that the user had been created successfully, but when I tried to get hold of the user profile that I had just added in the command line, by running the following commands:

```
from employees import models

from employees.models import Employee

allEmps = Employee.objects.all()

newUser = allEmps.filter(first_name = "name")
```

`newUser` just became an empty array, so clearly the user has not been added to the database... If I run the same commands, but using my name, rather than the name of the user I've just tried adding, `newUser` holds an array of one element (my user account), which I can then assign to a variable in order to check its properties, etc.

How do I actually add a new user to my Django project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `git clone` is the command you want to use.
When you run `git remote -v` on your own machine it will show you the location of the git repository that you are using. Note, that it might look like `username@example.host.com:/path/to/repo.git` if you are using SSH. I.e. it might include your username. So you will have to substitute that with your new colleague's username.

Where you run `git clone` from is totally up to you, but building a similar directory structure as you are using might make sense. Just running `git clone username@example.host.com:/path/to/repo.git` would create a new directory `repo` and clone into that. This is because in the example the repository is called `repo`. But `git clone` optionally takes a second argument to name the directory it will clone into. E.g. running `git clone username@example.host.com:/path/to/repo.git myapp` will create a new directory `myapp` in the current folder and clone into that.

Also have a look at [First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) if you want to set things like username, editor, mergetool, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to check- I ran `git remote -v` on my own machine, and the output it gave was: `origin git@bitbucket.org:myProgram/root.git (fetch)    origin git@bitbucket.org:myProgram/root.git (push)`. I do use SSH to connect to the remote server & `git pull` changes that I have `pushed` & restart the server, etc, but it doesn't seem to have shown my username- so do I need to worry about that at all? Presumably then, I can just run `git clone git@bitbucket.org:myProgram/root.git` from the `root` folder that I create manually on their computer?

Comment: Or would I run that from the folder that is 'up' one level, as the command will  create the `root` folder? i.e. run `git clone git@bitbucket.org:myProgram/root.git` from the `myProgram` folder that I have manually created on their computer?

Comment: @someone2088 You will run it from the `myProgram` folder and git will create a directory called `root` since that is the name of your repo. As it looks like everybody is using the same username `git` to log into your bitbucket repo you would not have to worry about that. However, make sure to set correct user info with `git config --global user.name "John Doe"` and `git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

Comment: Thanks- I will carry on with shortly, but I've just edited my OP to ask a follow up question, which is actually a bit more urgent- how would I add a profile for the new employee to the existing Django project, as they will also need access to this in order to work on it?

Comment: @someone2088 Your edit would better be posted as a separate question as it has nothing to do with your first question and git. So I recommend accepting an answer for this question and posting a new question about django with appropriate tags to get better answers in less time.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks

Comment: When you say to make sure to set correct user info- I nee to do this on the new employees's computer prior to setting up the local repo?

Comment: I tried setting up the user info as you said, and then ran `git clone git@bitbucket.org:myProgram/root` but got a message saying: `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository`... why is this? It didn't give me an option to enter a password at all...

Comment: SSH is using key authentication not passwords. Make sure that you have the correct keys installed and git is using them to authenticate. You can test your setup with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`. Also see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all about replicating folder structure.

As you can't move the installations from one to another.So you need to install in that newuser PC also.

He(new user) can work/install Django wherever he wants but I would recommend to keep apps separate/modular and Considering you kept apps **modular**,you can follow this steps:

**Your Side :**

1. Find your remote and push your code to github/bitbucket(for each app)

**New User PC :**

2. Make a folder with his name as : mkdir workspace_XXX
3. Inside that folder,Make project folder as : project_xxx
4. Inside that folder,Create VirtualEnv and Install Django /other packages
5. Now create the project with same name
6. now clone apps from git

Is it not recommended to make changes at django core but still some will do. If so,you can add those changes manually.

And I would recommend you to have some try about git here https://try.github.io/

Comment: I have pushed my code to github/ bitbucket, and on my machine on `master` branch, if I run `git status, it tells me that there's nothing to commit & that the working directory is clean. So the live version of the project is in a working state, is up-to-date with my local code. I have already installed Python 2.7.11 & Django 1.9.6 on their computer. I have also installed Sublime (the text editor I'm using for development), so all I want to do is replicate the same folder structure as I have, and 'download' the latest copy of the code from the remote repo...

Comment: @someone2088 so install the same project and apps there and git init those apps and git add remote upstream2 <codelink> for each app